# I am getting this error in my C code for valid parenthesis string

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I am student and I have been assigned to do the leetcode problem 1021 in C.
I have to solve this problem using stacks so I created one in C.
The stack is an integer stack but it's only purpose is to keep a track of weather the tempString has become a valid parenthesis string or not.

The error that I am getting is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJcl.png)

```
#define STACKSIZE 100


typedef struct{
    int top;
    int item[STACKSIZE];
} stack;

int isEmpty(stack* x)
{
    if(x->top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isFull(stack* x)
{
    if(x->top==STACKSIZE-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int pop(stack *x)
{
    if(isEmpty(x))
    {
        printf("UNDERFLOW");
        exit(1);
    }
    return x->item[x->top--];
}


void push(stack* x, int y)
{
    if(isFull(x))
    {
        printf("OVERFLOW");
        exit(1);
    }
    x->item[++x->top] = y;
}


int peek(stack* x)
{
    if(isEmpty(x))
    {
        printf("There are no elements to peek");
        exit(1);
    }
    return x->item[x->top];
}

void removeChar(char* x, int y)
{
    int i=y;
//  printf("First Character: %c\n",x[0]);
    while(x[i]!='\0')
    {
        x[i] = x[i+1];
        i++;
    }
}

void clearString(char *c)
{
    c[0] = '\0';
}





char * removeOuterParentheses(char * s){
    stack x;
    char tempString[] = "";
    // char* finalString = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char)*100)); //TO be returned
    char finalString[] = "";
    int startIndex=0;
    int endIndex=0;
    int count=0;
    while(count!=strlen(s))
    {
        if(isEmpty(&x) && strlen(tempString)!=0)
        {
            //This implies that the tempString is a primitive parenthesis string and we must add it to the final string after removing the outer parenthesis
            removeChar(tempString,0);
            removeChar(tempString,strlen(tempString)-1);
            strcat(finalString,tempString);
            clearString(tempString);


        }
        if(s[count]=='(')
        {
            push(&x,1);
            count++;
            strcat(tempString,"(");
        }
        else if(s[count]==')')
        {
            pop(&x);
            count++;
            strcat(tempString,")");
        }
    }

    return finalString;


}
```

Please tell me what is the error in my logic or my code or my implementation.
I am getting the error in line 46, i.e, within the push() function , in the statement     x->item[++x->top] = y;

Please Please Please help me. It's difficult to find an answer that is related with C.

The [LeetCode Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-outermost-parentheses/) Number is 1021.

Comment: `++x->top` should be `++(x->top)`. Check the operator precedence table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: No need for a stack if only one parenthesis type. Just count +1 on `(`and -1 on `)` and if the count goes below zero there is a missing `(` at the beginning, if you end with a positive number then missing `)`at the end...

Comment: What language are you using `C` or `C++`?  Only tag one language.

Comment: `char tempString[] = "";` creates an array of size 1, just enough for the terminating 0. Access outside those bounds is undefined behavior. Same for `finalString`.

Comment: ++x->top bumps the top element. -> is higher precedence than ++. The parens suggested are unnecessary.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès ordinarily I'd agree with you, but as a school assignment it sounds like they're being forced to use a stack.

Comment: You might want reconsider your error handling strategy of `exit(1)`.  Tell caller what the problem is and let them decide what to do.

Comment: `removeOuterParentheses()` returns pointer to a stack variable `finalString` which is out of scope after the return.

Comment: Please revise question and post a [mre] (i.e. failing test case in `main()` is a great way).

Comment: You don't initialize the stack `x`.

Answer (score 0):

0. Added missing includes.
1. `removeOuterParentheses()`: you need to initialize the `stack x`.  You could just do `stack x = { .top = -1 };` but I wrote an `init()` to do it for you in line with other stack functions.
2. `removeOuterParentheses()`: `tempString` and `finalString` are initialized to size 0. `finalString` needs to be roughly the size of the initial string.
3. `removeOuterParentheses()`: `return finalString;` a pointer to a local variable which is out of scope when function returns.
4. As you are using a `stack x` anyways, you might as well store position you need when appending the next chunk of data.  This allows you to eliminate some of your helper functions and the `tempString`.
5. Prefer `for()` loops for iteration.
6. Added a `main()` with test driver.  Test data was obtained from the question you mentioned https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-outermost-parentheses/.
7. `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` can be simplified by just returning the result of the expression.
8. (Not fixed) `top` is currently the "position of the last value written". You need a special `-1` to indicate that the stack is empty which means `top` has to be a `signed type` but the only negative value you use is that `-1.  If you redefine` top`to be the "position of next write" which is the same as "number of current elements in the stack" then the`top`can be an unsigned type and all values are you used up to`STACKSIZE`.
9. (Not fixed) For an abstract data type like your stack, it would be a better error handling strategy if you allow the client to decide what to do instead of `exit(1)`.  For example, by returning an error code, for example from an `enum`.  This makes the more complicated, and the caller now have to deal with errors.  On the other hand it makes your stack useful in other contexts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACKSIZE 100
typedef struct {
    int top;
    int item[STACKSIZE];
} stack;

int isEmpty(stack* x) {
    return x->top == -1;
}

int isFull(stack* x) {
    return x->top == STACKSIZE - 1;
}

void init(stack *x) {
    x->top = -1;
};

int pop(stack *x) {
    if(isEmpty(x)) {
        printf("UNDERFLOW");
        exit(1);
    }
    return x->item[x->top--];
}

void push(stack* x, int y) {
    if(isFull(x)) {
        printf("OVERFLOW");
        exit(1);
    }
    x->item[++x->top] = y;
}

int peek(stack* x) {
    if(isEmpty(x)) {
        printf("There are no elements to peek");
        exit(1);
    }
    return x->item[x->top];
}

char *removeOuterParentheses(char *s) {
    char *finalString = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if(!finalString)
        return NULL;
    *finalString = '\0';
    stack x;
    init(&x);
    for(size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if(s[i]=='(')
            push(&x, i);
        else if(s[i]==')') {
            int pos = pop(&x);
            if(isEmpty(&x))
                strncat(finalString, s + pos + 1, i - pos - 1);
        }
    }
    return finalString;
}

int main(void) {
    struct test {
        char *input;
        char *output;
    } tests[] = {
        {"(()())(())", "()()()"},
        {"(()())(())(()(()))", "()()()()(())"},
        {"()()", ""}
    };
    for(struct test *t = tests; t < tests + sizeof(tests) / sizeof(*tests); t++) {
        char *got = removeOuterParentheses(t->input);
        if(strcmp(t->output, got))
            printf("not ok\n# Expected: \"%s\"\n# Received: \"%s\"\n", t->output, got);
        else
            printf("ok\n");
        free(got);
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
ok
ok
ok
```

Comment: ++x->top and ++(x->top) are equivalent; the parens change nothing.